# Getting the index # of a TCollection Item when added to a TCollection

Tags: delphi, indexing, tcollection, tcollectionitem

I know that when I add a collection item to a collection, the index is zero-based.  I would like to make it one-based and show the value in a property called `Id`. Can someone tell me how I can go about this in code?

```
TCVSClassItem = class(TCollectionItem)  
private  
 fId: Integer;  
 function GetId: Integer;  
public  
published  
 property Id: Integer read GetId;  
end;  

function TCVSClassItem.GetId: Integer;  
begin  
 result:=  ????  
end;
```

Comment: Beware. `TCollectionItem` already has [a property named `ID`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TCollectionItem.ID). Also, there's little point in making a property published if it can't be edited since it won't be displayed in the Object Inspector.

Comment: OK, thanks, but, it was an example...so lets say the property name is SeqNo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

result := Index+1 should do it if I understand correctly your needs

Comment: You understood it correctly. It is the answer and what i was looking for. I had that earlier and could not compile. Turns out it was another issue. Thanks for keeping me on course.